# Is elinks the only text-based browser that has extensible support for scripts like lua?

Tags: browser, lua, scripting, text-based, elinks

Extensibility by lua scripting has made me choose `elinks` text-based browser among the many alternatives out there. However, it is not obvious to me and hard to pinned down if wither the other text-based browsers also support some kind of extension scripts. For example, with `elinks` there are hook lua scripts that allows me to intercept URLs that I visited and I can then programmatically do something on these. What are other text-based browsers having script support like this?

Comment: According to our [on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) guidance, "**Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above:**...Questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic..."

Comment: This is not about asking for recommendation. I am looking for other text-based browsers that has equivalent in-built scripting power underneath. elinks has it.

Comment: It's off-topic to ask us to either recommend *or* find.

Comment: Not text-based but probably interesting anyway: https://luakit.github.io/